# Expanding a displayed table by 'clicking' 'Show More' while scraping with webdriver in Python

Tags: selenium, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the content of this page:
https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/arcx/vdc/portfolio using BeautifulSoup and the selenium webdriver, and I have no problem doing so with all the content until I get to the 'Holdings' table, which by default shows only the top 10. I would like to get the top 25, which it will show when one clicks the 'Show more holdings' button. I 'inspected' the elements, and it seems like there is a javascript called to 'expand'

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-linkbinding="expand" class="more-data mds-link"><span>Show Fewer Holdings</span> <sal-components-mds-icon name="angle-up" size="small" fill-color="#006fba" class="sal-component-mip-holdings-read-more more-data-label" vce-ready=""><span class="sal-component-ctn sal-component-mds-icon"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="mds-icon mds-icon--s" style="fill: rgb(0, 111, 186);"><title></title> <use xlink:href="#angle-up--s"></use></svg></span></sal-components-mds-icon></a>
```

but I do not know how to 'expand' this when calling the webdriver? Which would be the right element I would need to change to achieve this?
Thank you!

Comment: You may need something like :   
https://seleniumbyexamples.github.io/cssselectorclassmultiple  
https://seleniumbyexamples.github.io/formbutton  

clicking an href is same as clicking a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BS4 is an html parser you want to use Selenium. Also wait for the element after page load to be clickable and then simply grab the element and click it.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/arcx/vdc/portfolio')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.more-data.mds-link"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using BS4,I didn't know how to write the part after .until, that was exactly what I was looking for! Many thanks

Comment: I did upvote, but it said b/c I don't have enough messages, it won't show the upvote :-(

Comment: BTW, I tried the same command to enable clicking in the webdriver one of the 5, 10, 15-year buttons on another page, but it gave me a blank error: the command was WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#yr10mpt"))).click()     and the webpage is  http://performance.morningstar.com/funds/etf/ratings-risk.action?t=VDC  Thanks!

Comment: Oh then accept it by using the checkmark for answer. Post the new question and I'll help you with it shortly.